# Confusion on delegate ownership

Tags: objective-c, delegates

> For example, `WhereamiViewController` owns the `CLLocationManager`,
>   and the `CLLocationManager`'s delegate is the
>   `WhereamiViewController`.

I'm confused on how the `WhereamiViewController` owns the `CLLocationManager` class when all `WhereamiViewController` has is an instance variable referring to an object of the class `CLLocationManager`. Could somebody help clear this concept to me?

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>

@interface WhereamiViewController : UIViewController <CLLocationManagerDelegate> {
    CLLocationManager *locationManager;
}
@end
```

---

```
#import "WhereamiViewController.h"

@implementation WhereamiViewController

-(id) initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];

    if (self) {
        locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
        [locationManager setDelegate: self];
        [locationManager setDesiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyBest];
        [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

Comment: Weak references, my friend, weak references.

Comment: The WhereamiViewController doesn't own the CLLocationManager class, it owns the instance, locationManager, since it created it with an alloc init.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CLLocationManager`'s delegate is not retained according to the [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CLLocationManager/delegate):

> @property(***assign***, nonatomic) id delegate

So, your delegate is not retained by the `CLLocationManger`, thus there is no retain loop.